# The more elegant way to code an arbritrary number of for imbrication levels

Tags: python, pandas, nested-loops

To better explain the problem, I'll give some specifics using the pandas library but I think the central idea of the question is quite general, as stated by the title.

The general question: What is the more elegant way to code an abritrary number of loop imbrication.

Specific example: take a function *doStruf(df, listLevels)* with df being a pandas DataFrame object and listLevels being a list of the names of hierachically organized features (e.g., person, classrooms, schools, ..., states) of the observation units described in df. For *doStruf(df, ["person", "classes", ..., "states"])* I would like the doStruf function to make something like

```
for person in unique(array(df["person"])):

    personData = df[df["person"] == person]
    for classroom in unique(array(personData["classrooms"])) :
        classroomData = personData[personData["classroom"] == classroom]

        ... arbritrary number of loops imbrication depending on len(listLevels) ...


             varYData = varXData[varXData["varY"] == varY]
             for state in unique(array(varYData["states"])) :
                 stateData = varYData[varYData["state"] == state]

                 ... do stuff using stateData ...
```

What is the cleaner way to deal with this kind of runtime-defined number of loop imbrications?

Comment: @Andy Hayden It has been edited.

Comment: Thinking about it, I guess recursivity might be the best way to go (I'll give a piece of code if no one else has a better suggestion) but I would very much appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Is the groupby not working for you?

Comment: @Andy Hayden It is not bad for use with pandas (although it misses the general aspect of the question). For the particular application I have in mind (which uses pandas), I'll benchmark its speed against a recursive solution. As I have HUGE DataFrame, I tends to make a "sub-dataframe" at each loop level rather than just making operation on DataTmp = Data[Data[var1] == "var1" and Data[var2] == "var2" and ...] because this tends to decrease significantly the processing time (at least in R).

Comment: Surely with the groupby (my answer) there is *way* less overhead than doing that? Please explain why you think it's not general enough.

Comment: @Andy Hayden The groupby function seam indeed to be coded efficiently: it is about 9% faster than a recursive solution I tested. As for generality, I said it is not very general as it is dependent on pandas. Does well for my particular application though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html):

```
g = df.groupby(['person', 'classes', ..., 'varY', 'states'])

g.apply(lambda stateData: do_stuff(stateData))
```